# What should our help center documentation contain?

Tags: discussion

**Edit: Now that we have some moderators, hopefully we can start moving towards getting a basic draft ready.**

As you can see, our pages that list types [on-topic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is currently set to the default, which is not site specific. This post is for getting some ideas as to what this documentation should contain about what types of questions fall within the scope of this site. Your answer should look something like this (and this is copied from Super User's page):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. …
>
> **Ask about...**
>
> Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking
>
> Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> **Don't ask about...**
>
> Anything not directly related to computer software or computer
>   hardware
>
> Questions that are primarily opinion-based
>
> Questions with too many possible answers or require an extremely long
>   answer
>
> Videogames, consoles, or other electronic devices, unless they connect
>   to your computer
>
> Websites or web services like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
>
> Shopping, buying or product recommendations
>
> Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks

Make sure to include types of off-topic questions in your answer as well.

## This is not final; we just need some basic suggestions to get started.

Comment: There have been a number of meta posts so far regarding whether certain topics should be on-topic or not. I would start with a summary of any conclusions from them, and put them into a template as above. That would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Language Learning is for language learners, language teachers and anyone interested in the concepts of language learning.
>
> **Ask about...**
>
> - Language learning or teaching techniques and methods. If the question relates to a specific language but can be generally applicable to a wide variety of languages, it is considered to be on-topic.
> - How objectively effective learning or teaching techniques are
> - Whether studies show certain trends on language learning or teaching techniques
> - Using language learning or teaching software or technology (ex. Duolingo, Anki, etc.) in conjunction with the learning/teaching process
>
> **Don't ask about...**
>
> - Questions about the Language Learning site (those go on [Meta Language Learning](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com))
> - Language features specific to one language should go to the relevant language site, unless the question is specifically about the **techniques** used to learn a language
>   e.g. Spanish questions should go to Spanish Language.
> - Translation requests, or rating the quality of a translation
> - Proofreading requests (Did I write this correctly?)
> - Requests or Recommendation for resources (books, software, websites)
> - Questions that can be answered with a simple web search
> - Questions that can be answered with little more than a *Yes* or *No*.
> - Questions about computer software, unless they are specific to language learning operations or capabilities
> - Questions about programming or computer languages
> - Questions about animal communication
> - Questions like *What language should I learn?*
>
> Please make an effort to research your question before posting it, and be sure to add as much detail as you can when explaining your problem. The more you can tell us, the better answers you'll receive!

Comment: I've edited your answer significantly, please make sure it fits within what you are trying to say.

Comment: I would add this text (borrowed from ELL) in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Please make an effort to research your question before posting it, and be sure to add as much detail as you can when explaining your problem. The more you can tell us, the better answers you'll receive!" This might help for questions that are too broad or unclear as to what is being asked.

Comment: @Quill It is not part of the lists, which is why I wrote this as a comment.

Comment: @user3169 resource requests aren't on-topic on Meta

Comment: I added a line for handling resource requests, for example [What resources can I use to fully understand grammar while using Duolingo?](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/630/what-resources-can-i-use-to-fully-understand-grammar-while-using-duolingo). While how to handle these maybe isn't decided yet, [Are resource request questions on-topic?](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/160/are-resource-request-questions-on-topic), something will need to go in these lists.

Comment: @Quill Well they need to be addressed somewhere. Lists of various resources in numerous questions isn't so useful.

Comment: They need to be addressed in the text, however, asking questions about resource requests is not on-topic at Meta. Meta is for asking questions about the Language Learning site, not about language learning

Comment: @Quill Please look at [Resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) and [Resources for learning Japanese](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) for examples of what I am talking about. At the least, resource questions can be directed to such posts.

Comment: Then we need to actually have those posts for a start instead of directing all resource requests to Meta

Comment: I added "If the question relates to a specific language but can be generally applicable to a wide variety of languages, it is considered to be on-topic." to your first bullet point under on-topic to help clarify it. Also, I added this new bullet point for on-topic questions: "Using language learning or teaching software or technology (ex. Duolingo, Anki, etc.) in conjunction with the learning/teaching process." Hope you don't mind :)